# What is the best SGDB for Riak kv - Basho?

Tags: riak, riak-cs, riak-js, basho-client

I'm starting with [riak](http://basho.com/products/riak-kv/), Is there any SGDB for linux that contemplate it?
As if it were [studio 3t](https://studio3t.com/) for MongoDb.

thankful

Answer (score 0):

You can use Riak Explorer (https://github.com/basho-labs/riak_explorer) together with Riak Explorer GUI (https://github.com/basho-labs/riak-explorer-gui), however they are not that easy to get working.